# JNLP extension installer runs before JRE installation

Tags: java, deployment, jnlp, java-web-start

I have an extension installer that always runs before the new java jre is installed on the client side. I need it to run afterwards. According to the JNLP spec:

1. ..
2. ..
3. Determine the right JRE to use. This might require downloading and installing the appropriate JRE.
   (See Section 4.6.2.)
4. Download extension descriptors for all the extensions used in the JNLP file. This step continues
   recursively with the extensions specified in the downloaded extension descriptors. Section 6 specifies
   how extension descriptors are downloaded and cached.
5. Run the installer for any required extension for which the installer has not yet been run. This is
   explained in Section 5.6.

....
the installer should run after downloading the new JRE, if I understand correctly? (but it does not, is starts right away)